# hide and expand layout

Tags: android

I am have one problem.

There is a `layout` with text `Follow`. and other `layout` with more design.

I want to hide and expand the `second layout` ,on click of `First layout`.

but `First layout` should always visible.

any idea .

Comment: is it a listView? or.. ? I think some figures could help

Comment: no both are linear layouts

Answer (score 0):

You do not need animation but with the use of **setting Layout parameter dynamically**. Set a OncliclikListener on the  `follow` and change the layout parameter of other `layout`.

```
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 144));
```

This is the simplest way to achieve your desired result.